# Groovy - Set your own property of an Integer

Tags: groovy, integer

I just started to learn Groovy and wondering if you can set your own property for an integer. For example,

```
 def a = 34.5.plus(34.34)
 def b = 5.64.minus(3.43)
 def c = 12.64.multiply(33.43)
```

In the above there are certain methods like `plus` `minus` and `multiply` 
What should I do if I want to define some of my own methods for integers like that.

I searched `Google` but couldn't find much about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can just add methods to the metaClass of `Integer`.

Here's an example:

```
Integer.metaClass.zeds = { -> 'z' * delegate }

assert 3.zeds() == 'zzz'
```

You can also add methods to a single instance of integer should you wish to, ie:

```
Integer num = 4
num.metaClass.halved = { -> delegate / 2.0 }

assert num.halved() == 2.0
```

You can also add methods to classes via Extension Methods a good explanation of which [can be found over here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html)

It should be noted (as you originally tagged this question as Java) that obviously, Java code will have no knowledge of these things, as it doesn't know about the metaClass

Answer (score 0):

Use groovy meta programming, this allows you to create dynamic method creation atruntime in the class that you want to place in .

bydefault if a method is not found methodmissing exception throws , this is where groovy allows you add method at runtime  for more reference  use the below comprehensive link

http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html

If this answer helps , dont forget to click answered.